# NiFi FetchFTP delete process getting failed for some of the files

Tags: apache-nifi

NiFi version 1.5.

i use FetchFTP configured as shown below:

```
Hostname: x.x.x.x
port: 21
username: yyy
password: zzz
Remote File: ${path}/${file_name}
Completion Strategy: Delete File
Run Schedule: 5 sec
```

50 files are processed by FetchFTP and out of which only 46 is successfully deleted the file from the FTP server.
Instantly, the processor showed the below error message and also in the log file:

```
2019-11-20 23:33:25,542 WARN [Timer-Driven Process Thread-6] o.a.nifi.processors.standard.FetchFTP FetchFTP[id=53ee29a5] Successfully fetched the content for StandardFlowFileRecord[uuid=8ec8219e,claim=StandardContentClaim [resourceClaim=StandardResourceClaim[id=15742604, container=default, section=175], offset=49, length=598026],offset=0,name=20191118145221190.pdf,size=598026] from x.x.x.x:21/<folder>/20191118145221190.pdf but failed to remove the remote file due to java.io.IOException: Failed to remove file /<folder>/20191118145221190.pdf due to 550 The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
```

Appreciate for any help regarding this.

Comment: You should check which process is using that file and also check if any permission issue.

Comment: there is no permission issue. if i re-run unprocessed 4 files, i was able to delete it. i dont know what is the exact error message that has been thrown.

Comment: `The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.`